# Static IP address for a specific hardware interface

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, wifi, static-ip

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and the on-board WiFi isn't strong enough for my needs. Thus, I have an USB WiFi that is plugged in there. I set its static IP address using `wlan1` and I thought that would be the end of it.

Alas, it wasn't. On some boots `wlan0` is on-board & `wlan1` is off-board, on other boots it's the opposite.

How can I make sure my static IP address is set to my USB WiFi dongle using its MAC Address or some other method besides interface name?

*Alternatively: Can I disable the on-board WiFi in a way that it will guarantee that* `wlan0` *will be allocated to my off-board WiFi?*

Comment: I could ask **how** (and **why**) did you assign static IP address, but that does not seem to be your question. You can write custom `udev` rules (not a trivial exercise). Googling "predictable network Interface names" will give you a lot about how this is implemented in `systemd`, although Raspbian does not seem to have implemented this feature (yet).

Comment: if wlan0 and wlan1 have different mac addresses simply add a dhcp reservation using the mac address of the usb wifi.

Comment: I used `/etc/network/interfaces`. I want a static IP address because it's a huge inconvenience when the IP changes; and yes, it does. I do not have access to the DHCP server, but I'm allowed to use addresses off of its allocation range.